# In TCP MultiThreaded Server, if a client gets service ,how to find the port number of servicing socket?

Tags: java, sockets, tcp, serversocket

In TCP Multi Threaded Server, if a client gets service ,how to find the port number of servicing socket?

From Sun Java tutorials

> When a connection is requested and successfully established, the `accept()` method returns a new "`Socket` object" which is bound to the same local port and has its remote address and remote port set to that of the client. The server can communicate with the client over this new `Socket` and continue to listen for client connection requests on the original `ServerSocket`.

How can I find the port number of the "`Socket` object"?

Comment: The port number of the new `Socket` is the same as the port number of the accepting `ServerSocket`, as your own quotation states. Unclear what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does [`Socket.getPort()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#getPort()) not do what you want? Or do you mean you want the local port (again, there's `Socket.getLocalPort()`? If you could give a worked example of what you're after, it would be easier to understand.

Here's a short example:

```
import java.net.*;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(50000);
        while (true) {
            Socket s = ss.accept();
            System.out.println("Local: " + s.getLocalPort() + 
                               "; Remote: " + s.getPort());
        }
    }
}
```

If you run that code and connect to it multiple times, you'll get output something like this:

```
Local: 50000; Remote: 17859
Local: 50000; Remote: 17866
Local: 50000; Remote: 17872
```

So `getLocalPort()` returns the port that was specified in the `ServerSocket` constructor, but `getPort()` returns a different port each time.

Comment: i tried that , it poits to the serversocket port specified in the constructor!!  but i want to know what is the port number of socket object created using serversocket.accept() method...

thanks in advance!!!

Comment: @billu: So you want the local port - did you try Socket.getLocalPort?

Comment: is the port number of serversocket object to listen for new client and socket object created to serve multiple clients in server program are the same ?

Comment: @Billy: I'm afraid I don't follow you. The connected socket should have a fresh local port.

Comment: @ashumeow: Please do not make edits like this, significantly extending an answer. You should have either added your own answer, or added comments here suggesting things I *might* want to add into the answer.

Comment: @billu Yes, they are the same. Jon's comment about 'fresh local port' is not correct, unless he is talk about the client's local port, which isn't what you're asking about

Comment: @EJP: Yes, I think I was a little confused in that comment - but calling `getPort()` definitely gives a different number each time. (The remote side of the port, but called on the server.) Will edit the answer to clarify.